# Simple example php using codeigniter Unable to access an error message

Tags: php, codeigniter, message

I´m following a tutorial, but I am getting this error:
Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name

I´ve searched, but I can´t find a solution. The program is very simple:
cformulario.php

```
<?php
class cFormulario extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    function mostrarDatos(){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtnom', 'Nombre', 'trim|required|min_lenght[3]|max_lenght[50]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtmail', 'Correo', 'trim|required|valid_email');

        if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
            $this->load->view('vformulario');
        }
        else{

            $datos=array(
                'nombre' => $this->input->post('txtnom'),
                'edad' => $this->input->post('txted'),
                'correo' => $this->input->post('txtmail')
            );
            $this->load->view("vformulario", $datos);
        }
    }


}
```

?>

vformulario.php

```
<body>
    <h1>Información Personal</h1>
    <br>

    <div id="error">
        <?php 
            echo validation_errors();
        ?>
    </div>
    <br>

    <?php
        echo form_open('cFormulario/mostrarDatos');
    ?>
    Nombre
    <input type="text" name="txtnom" id="txtnom" value="<?php echo set_value('texnom', '');?>"/>
    <br>
    Edad
    <input type="text" name="txted" id="txted" />
    <br>
    Correo
    <input type="text" name="txtmail" id="txtmail" value="<?php echo set_value('texmail', '');?>"/>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="Mostrar datos" />
    <input type="reset" name="Restablecer" />   

    <?php
        echo form_close();
    ?>

    <br>
    <div id="resultado">
        <?php
            if(!empty($nombre) && !empty($edad) && !empty($correo)){

                echo "Nombre: $nombre<br>";
                echo "Edad: $edad<br>";
                echo "Correo: $correo<br>";
            }
        ?>
    </div>

</body>
```

Weird thing is, it was working fine while I was typing it. But when I tried to show some results, the error came.

Comment: For starters you have a typo in min_lenght. It should be spelt as min_length

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you can add form_error("field_name") next to your field to get an error message.

for ex-

```
     <?php
        echo form_open('cFormulario/mostrarDatos');
    ?>
    Nombre
    <input type="text" name="txtnom" id="txtnom" value="<?php echo set_value('texnom', '');?>"/>
    <br>
    Edad
    <input type="text" name="txted" id="txted" />
<?php echo form_error('txted'); ?>
    <br>
    Correo
    <input type="text" name="txtmail" id="txtmail" value="<?php echo set_value('texmail', '');?>"/>
<?php echo form_error('txtmail'); ?>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="Mostrar datos" />
    <input type="reset" name="Restablecer" />   

    <?php
        echo form_close();
    ?>
```